# problema retornar opcion botones tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, radiobutton

NO CONSIGO RETORNAR LOS VALORES DE LOS 2 BOTONES CON UNA SOLA FUNCION

```
from Tkinter import *


def start():
        recuperacion= Recovery()

class Recovery():


    def __init__(self):

        global v

        recovery= Tk()
        v = IntVar()
        v.set(1)
        op1 = Radiobutton(recovery,text="Usuario",variable=v,value=1,command=self.selected)
        op2 = Radiobutton(recovery,text="Contraseña",variable=v,value=2,command=self.selected)

        op1.grid(column=2,row=2)
        op2.grid(column=2,row=3)

        recovery.mainloop()


    def selected(self):
        print v.get()



class login():
    def __init__(self):
        root= Tk()
        self.recovery=Button(root,text="Recuperar Cuenta",command=start)
        self.data_user=Entry(root)
        self.recovery.pack(side="bottom")
        root.mainloop()

ax = login()
```

Answer (score 0):

La causa directa de tu error es no pasar el padre a la variable cuando la instancias:

```
v = IntVar(recovery)
```

Ahora bien, unas cuantas observaciones:

- No debes usar nunca dos instancias de `tkinter.Tk` cada una con su mainloop en una misma aplicación. Si necesitas una nueva ventana usa `Tkinter.Toplevel`.
- Importar mediante `from módulo import *` (*widcard imports*) es por lo general una mala práctica y ha de evitarse.
- Te recomiendo mirarte las [convenciones de estilo definidas en PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), especialmente en lo referente a la forma de nombrar clases/funciones/métodos/etc. Son solo convenciones pero ayudan a la estandarización de tu código y a su legibilidad.
- Evita el uso de variables globales en lo posible. No necesitas hacer de `v` una variable global, lo normal ya que usas POO es que simplemente sea un atributo de instancia.

Teniendo lo anterior en cuenta y reestructurando algo tu código para hacer uso de las clases de una forma más natural tu código puede quedar así:

```
import Tkinter as tk   # Python 2.x
#import tkinter as tk  # Python 3.x


class Recovery(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        self.value = tk.IntVar(self)
        self.value.set(2)

        op1 = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="Usuario", variable=self.value,
                             value=1, command=self.selected
                            )
        op2 = tk.Radiobutton(self, text="ContraseÃ±a", variable=self.value,
                             value=2, command=self.selected
                            )
        op1.grid(row=0, sticky=tk.W)
        op2.grid(row=1, sticky=tk.W)

    def selected(self):
        print(self.value.get())


class Login(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        self.recovery = tk.Button(self, text="Recuperar Cuenta",
                                  command=self.recover_password
                                 )
        self.data_user = tk.Entry(self)
        self.data_user.pack(side="top")
        self.recovery.pack(side="bottom")

    def recover_password(self):
        Recovery()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Login(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: sigue sin funcionarme...te lo agradezco muchisimo pero sigo sin haber obtenido la solucion que es que al pulsar el boton op1 imprima 1 en pantalla y al pulsar op2 imprima 2 en pantalla ...muchas gracias por los consejos...soy principiante

Comment: @alextiberiuTelegaru tenia un error tonto con el uso de `super`, que solo tiene lugar en Python 2 al no ser `Tkinter.Frame` una clase de "nuevo estilo".  Lo he arreglado y probado el código, funciona sin problemas tanto en Python 2 como en Python 3 (cambiando el import).